# JAVA PHP Encryption Decryption

Tags: java, php, encryption, jax-rs

I have the following encryption function in my application:

```
public static String encrypt(String key, String value) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(key.substring(0, 16).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And in PHP the encrypted message is decoded using `openssl_decrypt()` with `AES-128-CBC` set as the method of encryption.

However the decryption always fails the response I get from the server is that it cannot recognize the encryption method.

I have no control over the server so I cannot change anything on that end only in my Java app.

I have tried different modes like `AES/CBC/NoPadding` but I get an exception

```
Input Length Not Multiple of 16 bytes
```

Now I know there is nothing wrong with the encryption because I am able to encrypt and decrypt in my java app when using `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` it just fails when post to the server.

Key is a md5 hash.

This is a sample of the data I need to encrypt:

```
{
    "merchant_id": "EXX-00000001",
    "user_id": "000000000001",
    "code": "000200",
    "details": {
        "acc_no": "1234691007924321",
        "exp": "07/19",
        "name": "MICHAEL XXXXXX",
        "type": "VIS"
    }
}
```

Only the "details" value is supposed to  be encrypted.  The code is supposed to be a md5 hash.  The resulting hash is then to be used as a key for the AES encryption. The IV is supposed to be the first 16 chars of the hash.  When the encryption is done the result should be encoded in base64 and sent to the server.

Comment: I think if you could share sample data, you are sending to server for decryption, will help to reproduce the issue.

Comment: First of all, try to encrypt data both in PHP and Java and compare results (if encryption works in the same way).

Comment: You can try the `echo 'Hello world' | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k 'my-key' | base64` and `echo 'U2FsdGVkX1+9jifaHib7bVTXHgziXZ0jsj2CpB6H+tc=' | base64 -d | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -k "my-key"` commands to check the commands locally and compare the output to the Java output

Comment: @hanish done that.

Comment: @Athlan I tried that and the result is not the same one of the reasons for my post here.

Comment: @user3151902 tried that in postman and the result was not the same when compared reason for me posting here.

Comment: Judging from your now [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640919/aes128-encryption-illegal-key-size-exception), since `key` is a Hex-encoded string of an MD5 hash (16 bytes), it is 32 characters long, since you take the bytes directly from that without Hex-decoding, your key is 256 bit (32 byte) long not 128 bit like `AES-128-CBC` suggests. Please get your specification of the encryption+encoding right, before going further. Or just show the full PHP code.

Comment: Btw, the output of MD5 are 16 bytes if you enabled raw output. So, IV and key should be equal (judging from your previous question).

Comment: I think you misunderstood, char length of a md5 hash is 32, I am using half of that for the IV.

Comment: @user3718908 Yes, but you use the whole thing for the key (`SecretKeySpec`) which is 32 bytes and therefore AES-256 and not AES-128.

Comment: Hmm I understand, quick question though in PHP what would happen if you used a 256 bit key but specified AES-128-CBS as the encryption method?

Comment: @user3718908 If I remember correctly, only the first 128 bits are used. (If you want to notify somebody specific in a comment thread when there are at least 2 other users beside yourself, you need to use @: [How do comment @ replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266187); I didn't receive your comment and just opened the question again to see whether there is new information)

Comment: I've voted to close this question as you're missing a protocol specification and the PHP code isn't presented either. That means it is simply impossible to verify a correct answer even if we wanted to.

Comment: The PHP code isn't necessary at all, I have described what my problem is, provided code, I have told you what function is being used, the key and the length, the IV, provided you with sample data for both the java side and the php side.  Exactly what protocol specification am I missing? I have followed all the guidelines in asking a question.

Comment: Questions should provide a [mcve], that make receiving a correct answer much more likely.

Comment: You would like me to compile the java program and send you a link? My issue is with the function which I have posted clearly along with data I am encrypting, encryption algorithm, key, iv etc. What exactly did I miss that makes you not understand my question? Tell me so I can add it.

Comment: Have you tried comparing what you send to the PHP server with what the server receives? The problem might be there as well. Also you wrote that there is nothing wrong with the encryption, that leaves the transmission and the decryption as possible error sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to reverse this, I got an error of

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size

at line

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
```

To make it work, I changed the `SecretKeySpec` byte array from `key.getBytes("UTF-8")` to `key.substring(0, 16).getBytes("UTF-8")` and used it like this:

```
    String md5Key= "e510a13edeea112b57683d724d5d70a6";
    String detailsData = "{\n" +
"        \"acc_no\": \"1234691007924321\",\n" +
"        \"exp\": \"07/19\",\n" +
"        \"name\": \"MICHAEL XXXXXX\",\n" +
"        \"type\": \"VIS\"\n" +
"    }";

    System.out.println(encrypt(md5Key, detailsData));
```

I got an output like this:

```
iufp4Rl+x/yTO7hSQBH7uU63sXAyzxgLequ3+JkFYZFz3PWwhxDC87TEC+bZ4rirgZVasrkLE1ehWWRGFV42Z29vAok+TMdwOvOettELUD3g8W2F40OyjMg4ItYkiZM+2W6Q2zf6t4sLzM6/AYqmAy1dKjPJcCQaFcnqK6mUFcM=
```

To decrypt that in PHP, I used the following code that uses the first 16 chars of `key` to use it as a `key` and `iv` initializer like this:

```
$enc_data = 'iufp4Rl+x/yTO7hSQBH7uU63sXAyzxgLequ3+JkFYZFz3PWwhxDC87TEC+bZ4rirgZVasrkLE1ehWWRGFV42Z29vAok+TMdwOvOettELUD3g8W2F40OyjMg4ItYkiZM+2W6Q2zf6t4sLzM6/AYqmAy1dKjPJcCQaFcnqK6mUFcM=';
$key = 'e510a13edeea112b57683d724d5d70a6';
$key16 = substr($key, 0, 16);
$key16Hex = unpack('H*', $key16);

print openssl_decrypt($enc_data, "AES-128-CBC", $key16, 0, hex2bin($key16Hex[1]));
```

And of course I got the wanted JSON data I encrypted with Java:

```
{
        "acc_no": "1234691007924321",
        "exp": "07/19",
        "name": "MICHAEL XXXXXX",
        "type": "VIS"
    }
```

It's strange you do not get an error at this line:

```
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
```

because I do using **JDK 1.8** with:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Comment: You were right, it would seem PHP probably truncates the key when you specify the method as AES-128 but pass a 256bit key, your answer helped me solved my problem works now!! Thank you!